# ModelState, TempData, ViewModel issue - new viewmodel value automatically gets overridden

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

This problem is best explained with code:

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {


        if (TempData.ContainsKey("ModelState"))
        {
            ModelState.Merge((ModelStateDictionary)TempData["ModelState"]);


            var viewModelA= new ViewModelA
            {
                 FirstName = "John"
            }
            return View(viewModelA);
        }
     }



    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> IndexPostActionMethod(ViewModelB model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            var result = await DoSomeStuff();
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                DoSomeOtherStuff();
            }
            else
            {
                AddErrors(result);
            }
        }





        TempData["ModelState"] = ModelState;
        return RedirectToAction("Index");

    }
```

The problem here is that when I post to `IndexPostActionMethod` and `DoSomeStuff()` returns `false` for some reason, the form/page is rediplayed by redirecting to `Index` and saving the `ModelState` in `TempData` during that redirect and then once the form/page is redisplayed, the value from `ModelState` (or where does it get the value from?) gets set as the value for a `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName)` and not the value that I set here: `var viewModelA = new ViewModelA { FirstName = "John"}`. Why can't I override the value and where does it get it from? It's like the framework is automatically updating `viewModelA` with whatever is in the `ModelStatDictionary` eventhough I create a new `ViewModelA` with a new value.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this. The way you should be handling a GET-POST-Redirect cycle is:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{

    var model = new ViewModel
    {
        FirstName = "John"
    }
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(ViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

        var result = await DoSomeStuff();
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            DoSomeOtherStuff();
        }
        else
        {
            AddErrors(result);
        }
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

`ModelState` rules all. Regardless of what you pass to the view explicitly, if the value is present in `ModelState` it will take precedence. Using `TempData` to pass the `ModelState` to another view is such a code smell, "smell" doesn't even really cover it.

If your only goal is to use one view model for the GET action and another, different, view model for the POST action, then you should really just stop and ask yourself seriously why you need to do that. In all the years I've worked with MVC, I've never had to do that, never needed to do that, and I can't imagine a scenario where I would need to do that.

**UPDATE**

So, based on the scenario you laid out in the comments, I would design it like this:

```
public class IndexViewModel
{
    public SomeTabViewModel SomeTab { get; set; }
    public AnotherTabViewModel AnotherTab { get; set; }
    public FooTabViewModle FooTab { get; set; }
}

public class SomeTabViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string SomeRequiredField { get; set; }
}

public class AnotherTabViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string AnotherRequiredField { get; set; }
}

public class FooTabViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string FooRequiredField { get; set; }
}
```

Basically, you break up the individual POST pieces into view models that altogether make up one big view model. Then, model validation only follows actual internal view model instances of the container. So, for example if you postback to `FooTab.FooRequiredField` only, then only `FooTab` is instantiated. The other two view model properties will remain null and will not be validated internally (i.e. the fact that they have required fields doesn't matter).

Comment: Building a complex shoppingcart page, a single page app kind of app,  with a large viewmodel for the GET action, and 5 smaller viewmodels for the POST actions. Which POST action gets called depends on user input. Need to preserve the route/url and to have built-in validation state available in subsequent page view so that's why I'm passing the ModelState from one actionmethod to another.

Comment: Could probably create a new question but since you seem to know a lot about these types of scenarios. If you have a large viewmodel for your GET action and you only want to pass a subset of your values to the POST action with the same name as the GET action and taking the viewmodel as parameter, and also ModelState.IsValid need to evaluate to true; how would you go about it?

Comment: Using tabs jquery plugin btw so some values will be null on POST and thus ModelState.IsValid will evaluate to false, which is not what I would want since those textboxes were hidden from the user.